# How to change the price of all the products with a constant variable according the weight of the products in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, commodity

I want to change the price of the products according to the weight with a variable amount. Such as silver, as the price changes on day to day basis so the price will be calculated with the amount I insert for 1gm silver.
For example, a product is of **300gm** and the price for **1 gm** silver is **2000** bucks then **300*2000 = 600,000 bucks**. The silver price will change daily and the price will be calculated according to that for all the products. 
Is there any plugin available for that or if it is possible with some code change I can do that. Help me out with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: I guess hiring a developer who can create a cronjob task for this, would be the best solution. The cronjob task (which could be just a PHP file), could update all product prices inside the wordpress database each day, based on the current value of silver for example. You don't want to use a plugin, cause in that case the script will only run once someone visits your website, and you don't want to slow down your page load because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an solution, which you can modify to your needs, basically what it does is bulk updating the price based on the price you entered ( Current Price per Gram ).

**Step 1**
Add a new page on `wp-admin` called "Price Update"

**Step 2**
Create a custom template on your theme's directory called `page-price-update.php` and paste the following snippet on that template file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if( is_admin() ) :?>

<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" >

    <p class="form-row">
        <label for="gram_price">Current Price of 1 Gram</label>
        <input type="number" name="gram_price" value="" />      
    </p>
    <p class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bulk_update_price" />
        <input type="submit" value="Update Now" />      
    </p>

</form>

<?php else : ?>

<h3>You need to be an Admin to access this page.!</h3>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Step 3**
Put the following snippet on your theme's `functions.php`

```
function bulk_update_price() {
    if( isset( $_POST["gram_price"] ) && is_numeric( $_POST["gram_price"] ) ) {
        // get all products
        $posts = get_posts( array('post_type'=>'product', 'posts_per_page'=>-1 ) );
        if( count( $posts ) > 0 ) {
            // iterare through each product
            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata( $post );
                wc_setup_product_data( $post );
                $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
                if( $product->has_weight() ) {
                    // get the current price entered i the form field
                    $current_price = floatval( $_POST["gram_price"] );
                    // get the product weight
                    $weight = $product->get_weight();
                    // well now set the price
                    $product->set_price( $weight * $current_price );
                }               
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<h1>Prices updated Successfully.!</h1>";
}
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_bulk_update_price', 'bulk_update_price' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_bulk_update_price', 'bulk_update_price' );
```

Now visit that page ( `http://your-domain/price-update` ) and do your price update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no plugin for that. 
Since the prices change daily, you should create a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) task as Erik van de Ven suggested. With that you can update the prices which you store in a database or in a file. Your wordpress-code can then read from that db/file, where the prices should now always be up to date